# How to use a wireless mic with computer mini speakers for trade show

Tags: amplifier

Working at our booth at a trade show, behind a table. I need gentle amplification to augment my voice when talking across the table to an handful of attendees. (Show floors are noisy!)

I have a wireless mic: https://www.pyleaudio.com/sku/PDWM1904. Output is a 1/2" male audio jack that is the same as the iPhone earbud jack.

And I have some cheap free-standing powered Gigaware speakers like these: http://www.ebay.com/p/Gigaware-2-0-Premium-Multimedia-Speakers-PC-Mac-4000378/1401540344.

I like these small speakers even though they're lo fi because I can discretely set them on the table.  They have the same 1/2" male audio jack (same sized as iPhone ear buds)

I tried using my Win 10 laptop as an amp. It worked great, but there's a tiny bit of disorienting lag.

How can I use these two together?  Do I need a small amp (that I can have delivered by Friday) to connect the wireless output to the speakers?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Those are powered speakers, at least they appear to be from a quick glance at the eBay page. Therefore, they have their own amplifier; you should be able to connect them directly to your microphone receiver.

BTW, some terminology: the jack/plug that you are calling 1/2" is known as a 1/8" or 3.5 mm plug (the diameter, not the length, is used to differentiate).

If you connect the speakers to the receiver using a simple straight through 1/4" TRS to 3.5mm TRS cable, it's likely that only one of the speakers will be active, as the output of the receiver appears to be unbalanced 1/4" TS (tip-sleeve). Therefore, you may need to buy or make a slightly more specific cable, one that connects 1/4" TS to 3.5mm TRS where the tip on the 1/4" side connects to both the tip and ring terminals on the 3.5mm side, thereby connecting the microphone to both right and left speakers.

Comment: Hi, uint128_t. Thanks for the response and clarification on terminology.  I'll try the direct connect approach you suggest.

Comment: It worked great on the show floor! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the space you're working in you may find yourself challenged to avoid feedback.  Depending on how long the delay is through your laptop you could practice your concentration and power through the distraction, using that delay as a way to prevent runaway squeals. That's an old school technique in stadium and arena PA systems... feels wierd for awhile, but it is possible!  (Talk slowly at first.)